# Angular 5/6 router: redirect a non existing route that has been defined with parameters

Tags: angular, angular-router

Let's suppose that I have a project that has these routes:

```
... /* Other routes */
{
    path: 'main/:category',
    component: CategoryComponent,'
},
{
    path: '404',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

Now let's suppose that I am surfing to `/main/category1` the route is working correctly.

But, if I am surfing to a route like this `/main/jshfsahgflkhghfdsiughisdfg` that is obviously a wrong route, I would like that this is redirected to the 404 page.

How can I do this?

Comment: why not just check the value when you first go to the category page?

Answer (score 5):

> But, if I am surfing to a route like this /main/jshfsahgflkhghfdsiughisdfg that is obviously a wrong route, I would like that this is redirected to the 404 page.

There is no pattern matching for route parameters in Angular (I wish there was). There isn't really an easy solution, but I've tried both of the following methods.

### Custom URL Matcher

Write a function that handles the route matching for that outlet. You can then use a pattern for the parameters that you want.

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

### Make 404 an application state

The problem with doing just this route:

```
{path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
```

Is that the page not found message is only shown for mismatched routes. It doesn't handle cases like invalid parameters, failure to load resolvers or failure to lazy load data.

Instead, display the 404 message in the application's main component.

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="notFound">Page is not found</div>
<router-outlet *ngIf="!notFound"></router-outlet>
```

Add logic to your template to display the 404 error and remove the `<router-outlet>` when the error is shown.

**notfound.service.ts:**

Create a service that will emit if the main component should display the 404 error message.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class NotFoundSerivce {
      public notFound = new Subject<boolean>();
 }
```

You can now add logic to your routers in the components to check for the parameter patterns or valid state. If the logic says it should be a 404, then use the `NotFoundService` to trigger the 404 error.

**page-not-found.component.ts:**

Update your current 404 component to trigger the `NotFoundService`.

Comment: creating a new service just for 404 is overkill

Comment: i didnt say i had a better answer, but this answer is overkill, the OP already had the best idea for the 404 service so it wouldnt be logical to change it

Comment: what doesnt make sense about me telling you that making a new service solely for 404 is overkill, its unnecessary excess code. having the 404 component as a wildcard match route is the better thing to do

Comment: `/main/fbuisbufbesuf` *WOULD* match a wildcard route such as `path: 'main/**'`

Comment: i have actually, i use it every day at work. i am not saying that `main/:category` wouldnt match, im saying that a wildcard such as `main/**` would also match. i dont believe you need to be so rude when i was only pointing out that your way might not be the best

Comment: @mast3rd3mon can you please add your own answer to this question and explain better your idea? I am not getting it

Comment: @Ferie i cant, its not an answer as such so posting an answer would be wrong to do